# Counting occurrences in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df like say:

```
value     id
 0        ABC
 1        ABC
 0        DAX
 0        ABC
 1        YTY
```

So, `value` is boolean and `id` is a string, there's more than 100 distinct strings.

How can I filter or group this df to get the id with the most '0' values, the id with most '1' values and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html), as follows:

```
df.value_counts()
```

The default is already with sorting by occurrences in descending order. So you can just refer to the first entry of `id` under each `value` to get what you want:

```
value  id 
0      ABC    2
       DAX    1
1      ABC    1
       YTY    1
dtype: int64
```

If you want to show only the max `id` for each `value`, you can also use:

```
df.value_counts().reset_index(level=1, name='count').groupby(level=0).first()
```

```
        id  count
value            
0      ABC      2
1      ABC      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
pd.crosstab(df.id,df.value).idxmax()
```